# Python char search in list

Tags: python, list

In my task I need to search specific char in lists (and list in list). If char is in list True should be printed.

My code:

```
def check(e,elem):
    if isinstance (elem,list):
        return exist(elem,e)
    else:
        return e == elem
        
def exist(elem,array):
    for e in aray:
        if check(e,elem):
            return True
            
    return False
    
exist('c', ['a',[['b','c'],'d', ['e']], 'f'])
```

With this code I only go trough a,d and f but loop wont check another chars.  And terminal get me an error on 'c', invalid character in identifier.

Comment: Take a close look at line 3 ``return exist(elem,e)`` and at line 7 ``def exist(elem,array):``

Comment: E is element of array, so I'm not sure what are u trying to say

Comment: Problem was with isinstance (e, list)

Comment: in ``check`` ``e`` is the character you're looking for, ``elem`` ist the list, while you're passing the list as ``elem`` to ``exists`` and the character as ``array``. Maybe you should consider to use verbose and consistent argument names.

Comment: I should write var names better

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
if isinstance(elem, list)
```

Correct:

```
if isinstance(e, list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected code:

```
def check(e,elem):
    if isinstance (e,list):
        return exist(elem, e)
    else:
        return e == elem
        
def exist(elem,array):
    for e in array:
        if check(e,elem):
            return True
            
    return False
```

**Testing:**

```
print (exist('c', ['a',[['b','c'],'d', ['e']], 'f']))
print (exist('c', ['a',[['b',['c']],'d', ['e']], 'f']))
print (exist('c', ['a',[['b',['a', 'c']],'d', ['e']], 'f']))
print (exist('c', ['a',[['b',['a', ['b', 'c']]],'d', ['e']], 'f']))
print (exist('c', ['a',[['b',['a', ['b', 'a']]],'d', ['e']], 'f']))
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
True
True
False
```